# Retrieving the element with GUID identifier using Jquery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am able retrieve the below div using the code `$(view1)`

```
<div id="view1"></div>
```

But with above jquery selector(`$(view1)`) is failing to retrieve if the id is GUID. Below is the div, which i am failing retrieve using Jquery selctors.

```
<div id="E6420731-B136-E611-80D4-00155D456789"></div>
```

I tried the below code to retrieve the above div but it is giving exception

```
$(E6420731-B136-E611-80D4-00155D427239)
```

How can i retrieve a div with id as GUID using Jquery selectors

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/ `$('#E6420731-B136-E611-80D4-00155D456789')` https://jsfiddle.net/9644jbcu/

Comment: "I am able retrieve the below div using the code $(view1)" Although that works, that's almost certainly not how you're supposed to retrieve it. For one thing, that's not a selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for confusing you all.

**I am not able to retrieve the div because id is case sensitive.**

I have an id like "e6420731-b136-e611-80d4-00155d456789" in the DOM and i am trying with "E6420731-B136-E611-80D4-00155D456789", that is why i could not able to retrieve the Div.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery, or actually Javascript in general, does not allow you to type strings without quotes. Next to that, you need a `#` hashtag before any ID parameter, or a `.` dot before any class selector.

---

```
$('#idname');
```

or

```
var idname = 'idname';
$('#' + idname);
```

or

```
var idname = '#idname';
$(idname);
```

---

You can select any element without JQuery too (no need for `#`):

```
var elem = document.getElementById("idname");
```

And then use it in JQuery like this:

```
$(elem);
```